# Limit Chromium cache size in Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, browser-cache, chromium

I need to limit the cache size of Chromium in my debian computer. I've tried to edit the `master-preferences` in order to solve this problem, but every time I reopen the browser this file restore its original values.
How can I modify this values to have for example a limit of 10M cache everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. An easy fix to this is to add the following argument to the command.

```
chromium-browser --disk-cache-size=n
```

say n is 500000000 this would be 500 MB

You can check to make sure it increased it by typing the following in your browser and then looking at the Max Size value.

```
chrome://net-internals/#httpCache
```

Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/104415/how-do-i-increase-cache-size-in-chrome/104429#104429

Comment: is there no way to set it as an option in Chrome itself?

Comment: the net-internals URL doesn't show me anything ("Statistics
Cache type: Simple Cache").  BUt in my case I'm trying to *decrease* cache size, not increase it.

Comment: Same that @Michael, I just see ("Statistics Cache type: Simple Cache") in two different computers. Even using Chrome or Chromium.